# Make trigger() run a function once only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 3 buttons and I've used their calss to create a click function.

```
$('.abc').click(function(e, elem){
     alert("triggered");
});
```

I've got another click function which triggers the above click function ( `$('.abc'). click function` ) by passing a value (val) from each case.

```
$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){
     // This is the triggered action name
     switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
     // A case for each action.
       case "case1": $('.abc').trigger('click',['first']); break;
       case "case2": $('.abc').trigger('click',['second']); break;
       case "case3": $('.abc').trigger('click',['third']); break;
     }
});
```

My question is, when I click directly on a button the alert shows one only. But 
when I click on a button in my other function ( `$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){`) the alert shows 3 times. How do I make the alert show once only when a click is done via `$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){` ?

```
$('.abc').click(function(e, elem){ // alert is shown once only 

$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){ // alert is shown 3 times
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the whole picture, e.g. your complete structure, but my first thought is that you might be having issue with event bubbling. Try adding `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` in `$('.abc.').click(function(e, elem) { // here`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are triggering click on every element in the collection, so you see alert 3 times, once per element.

You should trigger click on individual element only:

```
$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){
     // This is the triggered action name
     switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
     // A case for each action.
         case "case1": $('.abc:eq(0)').trigger('click'); break;
         case "case2": $('.abc:eq(1)').trigger('click'); break;
         case "case3": $('.abc:eq(2)').trigger('click'); break;
     }
});
```

And here is a demonstration of it.

```js
$('.abc').click(function(e, elem) {
     alert("Triggered " + $(this).text());
});

$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
     switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
         case "case1": $('.abc:eq(0)').trigger('click'); break;
         case "case2": $('.abc:eq(1)').trigger('click'); break;
         case "case3": $('.abc:eq(2)').trigger('click'); break;
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-menu">
    <li data-action="case1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-action="case2">Item 2</li>
    <li data-action="case3">Item 3</li>
</div>

<div class="abc">Element 1</div>
<div class="abc">Element 2</div>
<div class="abc">Element 3</div>
```